# getpeername() doesn't work with connections to localhost

Tags: c++, networking, sockets

EDIT: Restating the problem, if I am listening to port 54321 and a local process listening to port 12345 connects to me, creating socket `s`, how do I actually find the port it is listening on?

```
sockaddr_in addr;
int len = sizeof(addr);
getpeername(s, (sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
cout << string(inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr)) << ":" << ntohs(addr.sin_port) << endl;
```

Shouldn't the output be `127.0.0.1:12345`? Instead I get `127.0.0.1:62305`, or some other arbitrary port number. Is this an error on my part, or is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What do you mean "a local process listening to port 12345 connects to me"? Do you mean it called bind with certain port number? If yes, did you check bind's result, may be it failed and that's why you are getting arbitrary port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two processes listening on two ports - that's two listening sockets independent of each other. Then you create a third, client, socket in one of the processes and connect to the other one. That third socket gets an [ephemeral port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) assigned to it by TCP stack (62305 in your case). So the connection is represented by the tuple {source ip, source port, target ip, target port} - {127.0.0.1,62305,127.0.0.1,54321} here. This connection has absolutely nothing to do with any listening sockets the connecting process might have. You have to explicitly design your application to communicate port numbers among peers if you need to know them. If you just want to know what process has what sockets, there's always [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).

Comment: Gotcha, this is the mistake I was making in my reasoning. I figured when I use connect(), the resulting connection is somehow "associated" with the port I'm listening to, and will send/receive data over the same port. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on RageZ's answer, getpeername() is returning the **source** port and address of the other side of your socket.  Port 12345 is the address of the destination that you passed to bind().  In general, clients (e.g. telnet, nc, etc...) will not have called bind() on their socket because they don't want to listen for connections.  So the OS will assign them an arbitrary "ephemeral" port number.

In general, there is little to no utility in knowing the source port of a TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

getpeername give details about the client not the server so it make sense you get some random port.

you can see the [man](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/getpeername/) page

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should get `127.0.0.1:12345` if s is connected. Are you sure it's connected?

You need to check return code of `getpeername()` to make sure there is no errors.